# What is the difference between "tirada" and "difusión" and can you use "circulación" or "distribución" for either or both?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

First, my question repeated in Spanish:
Primero, mi pregunta repetido en español:

> **¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "tirada" y "difusión"? ¿Se puede usar "circulación" o "distribución" como sinónimo de alguna de ellas?**

Details in English:

I've been trying to translate some articles on newspapers and one of the things I've noticed is that the English word "circulation" seems to be getting translated as "difusión."  So, I did some research and stumbled upon the following over at WordReference:

> [**Qué es difusion, tirada y audiencia en los medios de comunicación?**](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070201033632AApAZmz)

After reading the information on that page, I got to thinking about how news is issued today and how so many are just as likely to read it online as they are to actually buy a newspaper.  I then got to thinking that perhaps this word -- difusión -- is the word used to refer to newspaper circulation in general.  Not entirely convinced and not wanting to rely solely on a discussion thread at WordReference, I went to the DRAE [(Diccionario de la Real Academia Española)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diccionario_de_la_lengua_espa%C3%B1ola) and discovered that its entry "difusión" made no reference to newspaper circulation at all.  In fact, below is the definition I found listed:

> **1.f.  Acción y efecto de difundir.
>
>   2.f.  Extensión, dilatación viciosa en lo hablado o escrito.**

*Source: Real Academia Española's entry for ["difusión"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DkYpJmy)*

The first means "action and effect of spreading" and the second means something like "extended, vicious expansion in speaking or writing."

All of this has left me with some degree of uncertainty regarding what might be the best word to use for "circulation."  So, if you have any insight on this, especially if you've worked in the publishing industry or have access to a glossary or dictionary that has good translations of publishing terminology, I'd love to know your thoughts on this.

Detalles en español:

He estado tratando de traducir unos artículos en periódicos y una de las cosas que he notado es que la palabra inglesa "circulation" parece estar traduciéndose como "difusión."  Entonces, investigué un poco y tropecé con lo siguiente en WordReference:

> [**Qué es difusion, tirada y audiencia en los medios de comunicación?**](https://es.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070201033632AApAZmz)

Después de leer la información en esta página, empecé a pensar en la manera en que las noticias están publicadas hoy en día descubriendo que la mayoría de los periódicos se pueden leer en internet lo cual provoca que la gente no esté dispuesta a comprarlos.  Entonces, empecé a pensar que la palabra -- difusión -- es la palabra usada para referirse a la circulación (?) de un periódico en general.  No completamente convencida, al no confiar solamente en un hilo de discusión en WordReference, fui al DRAE y descubrí que su entrada para "difusión" no hizo ninguna referencia en absoluto a la circulación (?) de un periódico.  De hecho, abajo está la entrada que encontré:

> **1.f.  Acción y efecto de difundir.
>
>   2.f.  Extensión, dilatación viciosa en lo hablado or escrito.**

Todo esto me ha dejado con cierto grado de incertidumbre sobre cuál es la mejor palabra para usar "circulation".  Por lo tanto, si sabes algo sobre este asunto, especialmente si has trabajado en alguna editorial o tienes acceso a algún glosario o diccionario que tenga buenas traducciones de terminología editorial, me encantaría saber sus conocimientos en éste.

---

This is my first attempt to try to write my question in both English and Spanish, so if you see a mistake (in either language), please let me know.  *(Though I am a native speaker of English, I have found that I discover new things about my own language all the time.)*

---

***One final note: I realize the WordReference discussion thread goes into some depth about this topic, but, unless I missed it, nobody who took the time to post a definition bothers to cite any sources.  So, for those who are able to answer this, if you can cite some sources in your answer, that would be even better.***

***Nota final: Me doy cuenta de que el hilo de discusión en WordReference contempla en cierto grado de profundidad este tema, pero, a menos que me lo perdiera, nadie de los que tomaron su tiempo para contestar citó fuentes.  Por lo tanto, para aquellos que puedan contestar éste, si puede citar unos fuentes en su respuesta, sería aún mejor.***

---

Finally, if you need a visual of what it is I'm talking about, here are some images of the infoboxes of some articles that have already been translated into Spanish.  Perhaps after seeing it, you'll understand better why I've been confused.

[image]

Comment: Una pregunta muy interesante y bastante [currada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Bk15xpi). Te dejo una respuesta en español para animarte a aprender aun más, dado que veo que tu dominio del idioma es bastante bueno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haces bien en desconfiar. La palabra inglesa *[circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newspaper_circulation)* significa, según la Wikipedia:

> [...] the number of copies it distributes on an average day.

La propia página advierte de lo siguiente:

> Circulation is not always the same as copies sold, often called **paid circulation**, since some newspapers are distributed without cost to the reader.

Y más aún:

> Readership figures are usually higher than circulation figures because of the assumption that a typical copy of the newspaper is read by more than one person.

¿Cómo se traduce esto al español? Pues volviendo a la Wikipedia pero esta vez en español, tenemos la definición de *[tirada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirada_(impresi%C3%B3n))*:

> [...] juego de piezas idénticas procedentes de la misma lámina, piedra, plantilla u otra superficie. [...] La tirada de una revista o periódico es el número de ejemplares del mismo que salen a la venta, se le denomina además **tiraje** o **circulación**.

Luego ahí tienes tu respuesta. La "tirada" de un periódico es el número de ejemplares que salen a la venta (que no quiere decir que se vendan al final), corresponde con el "circulation" inglés, y se denomina también "circulación". La "difusión" hace referencia al número de personas que finalmente acaban leyendo el periódico. Este número son siempre estimaciones: se estima el número de personas que acaba leyendo cada ejemplar vendido (o puesto en circulación en el caso de periódicos gratuitos).

Ejemplo del periódico de pago [La Razón](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Raz%C3%B3n_(Espa%C3%B1a)): tirada (o circulación) de 41671 ejemplares diarios de media, y difusión de 49481 lectores diarios de media.

Ejemplo del periódico gratuito [20 Minutos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_minutos): tirada de 297800 unidades al día, difusión de 1040000 lectores al día. Al ser gratuito y tener la cultura de ser reaprovechable (la gente lo deja en sitios donde otros puedan leerlo, en vez de tirarlo a la papelera), cada ejemplar es leído por mucha más gente.

Comment: Encontré su respuesta muy informativa y me gusta la manera en que acercarse un problema.  Debí de pensar en eso.  Bien hecho,  Voy a dar otros una oportunidad contestar esta pregunta, pero si no hay otras, siento cómoda dando su respuesta la marca verde.  Le agradezco para tomar el tiempo contestarla.